# How can i make my route inside menu in database same as my web.php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a question about routing. I make my menu as a database. Then when I click "job company" on my website, it gave me error *Route [company.insert_logo] not defined.* on my blade. I keep changing between my database and my blade but it doesn't work. I want to submit a form with image to the database. Below I attach my code

**my company.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('company.insert_logo') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="intro-y box p-5">
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Company</label>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <label class="input w-full border mt-2" align="right">Select Company Logo</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <input type="file" name="company_logo" />
                                            </div>
                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Position Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="input w-full border mt-2 form-control" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-right mt-5">
                                        <button type="button" class="button w-24 border dark:border-dark-5 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 mr-1">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="button w-24 bg-theme-1 text-white" name="store_company" >Save</button>
                                    </div>

                                    {{-- <input type="submit" name="store_image" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" /> --}}

                                </div>

                            </form>
                        
                        </div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('company', 'CompanyController');
```

I believe that I might write something wrong for my web.php but I am really not sure where.

Lets say I'm not using resource

**web.php**

```
Route::get('store_company', 'CompanyController@index');
Route::post('store_company/insert_logo', 'CompanyController@insert_logo');
Route::get('store_company/fetch_logo/{id}', 'StoreImageController@fetch_logo');
```

and I change my blade using URL instead of routing to

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ url('store_company/insert_logo') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I am still getting the same error which is routing for my company.index(inside my database menu) is undefined

Comment: [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) has a list of routes/actions when using resource routes. `'company.insert_logo'` is not one of them, you'd need to create a separate [Named Route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) for that

Comment: If I change this part *<form method="post" action="{{ route('company.insert_logo') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">* I still not getting it right. I change it into company.store

Comment: Tip: A screenshot of your database schema is almost always useless. When applicable include the cleaned up output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Use `\G` in the `mysql>` shell to keep it tidy.

Comment: @tadman sorry but I am not getting what you mean

Comment: That screenshot shows almost zero information and takes up a lot of space. The SQL version of same actually helps. It contains a *lot* of information.

Comment: I update my question with my table and menu seeder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use name for your route

for example

```
Route::post('store_company/insert_logo', 'CompanyController@insert_logo')->name('INSERT_LOGO');

{{ route('INSERT_LOGO') }}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error *Route [company.index] not defined.* I believe this is something to do with my menu inside my database but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @kins You still have the resource route, right? `Route::resource('company', 'CompanyController');` In addition to that, add the named route as mentioned in my comment

Comment: @brombeer yes but I am getting an error saying *Undefined variable: menu (View: C:\Usersxampp\htdocs\company\resources\views\layout\sidenav.blade.php)* I update my side-nave.blade.php on my question

Comment: @kins That sounds like it's not related to the question, a completely new error and new blade file. Is your question regarding the route resolved?

Comment: @brombeer hmm no it is not. It still getting error. Because whenever I click on company button on my side-nav menu, it showing the *undefined variable:menu* so I cannot view my company.blade.php

Comment: @kins To me it looks like the "_`undefined variable:menu_" error was there from the start, your route error just hit first. Now the route error/question is resolved, that menu error pops up. They seem unrelated. I can't imagine adding a route "suddenly" poses an "undefined variable" error. Please post a new question with all relevant info about this new error